# Type Mismatch when searching for numbers using Index/Match in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an index match formula which works fine when I'm searching for a string with letters in it, but returns an error of 1004 when I use it with a string of numbers. I tried changing application.worksheetfunction.match to application.match and it returns an error 13: Type Mismatch. I think that the issue is that it is unable to match a string containing only numbers, but I need a way to do so.

```
   application.worksheetfunction.index(sheet4.range("AMD[Product Number]"), _ 
   application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sheet1.Searchbox.Value,sheet4.Range("AMD[Model]"),0))
```

AMD[Model] column is formatted as general because it contains numbers (ex: 6128) and mixed (ex: 6262 HE) formats.
I don't think that it's relevant, but AMD[Product Number] column is formatted as general.

Is there any way that the code can be rewritten to make it work?

Edit: Here is some more of the code. I don't know how useful much of it is going to be. The code above is what was isolated as being the issue.

```
Dim SB As String, SBn As Boolean, FirstPN As String, FirstPNQTY As Long

SB = Sheet1.Searchbox.Text
            SBn = IsNumeric(SB)
            Select Case SBn
                Case True
                    FirstPN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet4.Range("AMD[Part Number]"), _
                                        Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SB, Sheet4.Range("AMD[Model]"), 0))
                    FirstPNQTY = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet4.Range("AMD[Qty]"), _
                                            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(FirstPN, Sheet4.Range("AMD[Part Number]"), 0))
                    With Sheet1
                            .tTitle5 = "Select Next PN"
                            .tField5.Text = FirstPN
                            .bTitle5 = "Current PN QTY"
                            .bField5.Text = FirstPNQTY
                        End With
```

Comment: I (rather) guess that made a mistake with closing paranthessis. It should be rather like this `....sheet4.Range("AMD[Model]"),0))`

Comment: I mistyped the formula in the question, but it is formatted properly in the workbook.

Comment: in which way `Searchbox` property is defined?

Comment: Searchbox is an activex textbox which is put in a variable, "SB", which is defined as a string.

Comment: You need to post more of your code. Please read the HELP pages for information as to[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `SB` is type String.  If it's value is numeric, it's still a string, only looks like a number.  If the numeric data in `AMD[Model]` is actually numbers then Match won't find it.

Comment: Some of the entries are only numbers and some are numbers and letters. shouldn't string match with general?

Comment: @Scionara, no, General is only cell formating, and has nothing to do with the data type. see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SB` is type String. If it's value is numeric, it's still a string, only looks like a number. If the numeric data in `AMD[Model]` is actually numbers then Match won't find it.

Solution is to change `SB` to Variant, and cast the string to a number

```
Dim SB As Variant
'....    
If IsNumeric(SB) Then
    SB = Val(SB)
End If
```